# What are the most important physics of hair dryers?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, humidity

I can think of at least three distinct mechanisms by which a hair dryer could remove moisture from hair, but I do not know which, if any, of them dominates.

1. **Mechanically remove the water.**  This method would entail the transfer of momentum from the air stream to water droplets, which would then break any binding force keeping the water on the hair, leading to the water flying away.
2. **Accelerate evaporation by replacing moist air with dry air.**  I can imagine that the water is evaporating, leading to the air directly adjacent to the water reaching 100% humidity.  The water vapor would need to disperse before more water could evaporate.  By using a blow dryer one continually pushes the humid air aside and replaces it with relatively dry air, accelerating the evaporation.
3. **Accelerate evaporation by bombardment.**  Finally, the air being pushed toward the water entails air molecules being launched at the surface of the water.  As the air molecules strike the water surface, they knock water molecules loose from the surface of water droplets.  I would believe this is always happening due to the non-zero motion of air molecules, but perhaps the blow dryer would increase the rate at which it happens.

Are all of these mechanisms real?  Do any of them dominate?  Is there a more important mechanism I have missed?

Comment: 4. Hot air driers cause faster evaporation of warmer water and high space capacity for vapor.

Comment: Good point!  I know that you can also use cold air, which is slower.  So heat has an important effect.  But I don't know if the heat dominates, as the differnce in time blow drying with cold air and not blow drying is much larger than the difference in time blow drying with hot and cold air.

Comment: I suspect that 2 is the dominant mechanism. I assume that you're not considering the use of *warm* air. This would increase the fraction of water molecules with enough energy to escape by evaporation.

Comment: I agree with Philip, Points 1/ and 3/ looks insignificant to me. Point 2/ dominates, being further boosted by thermal energy supply by cold or even hot air, blow, the latter also increasing vapor capacity.

Comment: When I used to test hair dyers (many years ago) designers told me 2 dominates. Heat was primarily for comfort

Comment: @BobD  well, ok , but the inlet air was at least at room temp, and presumably low RH.  By heating the air, the RH drops, allowing more evaporation from the hair/scalp.  That will be significant in humid climates.

Comment: Compare with a car wash, where rather high-flow-rate blowers do in fact push water off the car's surfaces.  Granted, a smooth high-surface energy car hood is quite different from a tangle of human hairs which are (microscopically) not smooth at all

Comment: Is there a Stack Exchange for "engineering" or technology questions?

Comment: @Mitchell Porter: I think there is, but I am more interested in the physics underlying this.  I don't actually care if it is drying hair or a car or anything else; I would like to know more about the physics of evaporation, and am using this context to ask about it.